# Syllable-counting function

Tags: c#, performance, .net

I was working on a syllable counting function for a text editor(this function is accurate enough). However, I would like to know if it is possible to optimize it, it already separated into another thread, but I would like to know if there is any kind of optimization that I can do with it to make it more efficient.

```
private static int SyllableCount(string word)
{
    word = word.ToLower().Trim();
    int count = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(word, "[aeiouy]+").Count;
    if ((word.EndsWith("e") || (word.EndsWith("es") || word.EndsWith("ed"))) && !word.EndsWith("le"))
        count--;
    return count;
}
```

It uses regular expressions, something that [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count) source mentions having poor performance in .net applications, is that the case? And if not, are there any other optimizations that I can perform on it?

Anyway, it does not lag much, but my application does use around four threads already, just for keeping up with various text entry statistics, so now I'm just trying to shave the fat off so to speak.

Comment: Is it currently too slow? It sounds like youve just heard that it might be slow. There's no need to optimize it until you've figured out if it's actually too slow.

Comment: You might be interested to know that you're not the first trying to achieve syllabification. Here's an answer of mine on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096228/counting-syllables-in-a-word/9096723#9096723

Comment: Of course, I already had the function, I wanted help optimizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Regex is going to be slow, by virtue of it being a very powerful, flexible engine that can't assume you'll never want to do something that a regex can achieve. This particular regex pattern is pretty simple (no lookbehinds, etc) but there will be some overhead inherent in Regex use which you can trim. You can iterate through the string and count occurrences of groups of vowels in linear time with very little overhead.

```
private static int SyllableCount(string word)
{
    word = word.ToLower().Trim();
    bool lastWasVowel;
    var vowels = new []{'a','e','i','o','u','y'};
    int count;

    //a string is an IEnumerable<char>; convenient.
    foreach(var c in word)
    {
       if(vowels.Contains(c))
       {
          if(!lastWasVowel)
             count++;
          lastWasVowel = true;
       }
       else
          lastWasVowel = false;                     
    }

    if ((word.EndsWith("e") || (word.EndsWith("es") || word.EndsWith("ed"))) 
          && !word.EndsWith("le"))
        count--;

    return count;
}
```

I'd A/B the above algorithm against the one you already have; you should see at least some performance increase. Notice that although this may well be faster as it does exactly what you want and doesn't see if you want to do anything else, it uses more LOC to achieve the same result. This is Regex's real power; powerful string analysis with very concise code.

Comment: Actually, there are a few errors, but they will be easy to fix. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yeah I found a few in my first attempt. The code as edited should be correct.

Comment: It turns out that my method was faster, however your method was seems to be more accurate, thanks.

Comment: Odd. the above code sample should behave identically to the regex-based algorithm.

Comment: awesome ty very much for this

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about regexp being slow, you could try a simple Split():

```
int count = word.Split(new char[] { 'a','e','i','o','u','y' }, 
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length ;
```

It would be easy to benchmark the difference.

Comment: This wouldn't count occurrences of two or more adjacent vowels as one "syllable", so "sail" would be counted incorrectly as having 2 syllables when the OP's algorithm would correctly count one.

Comment: @KeithS - fair point. Easily fixed by adding if (word.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a','e','i','o','u','y' } ) != word.Length - 1) count-- ; afterwards.